# Language of the page CakePHP 3

Tags: php, cakephp

I want to know the Language of the page i am working on. The application uses CakePHP 3
tried 
      `var_dump(I18n::getLocale());` but it didnt work. and yes i included the `use Cake\I18n\I18n;` into my file.

Comment: "but it didnt work"... what does that mean?

Comment: '(Error) - Call to undefined method Cake\I18n\I18n::getLocale() in /var/www/portal/src/View/Helper/CmsBlockHelper.php on 33'